# $_SERVER['document_root'] isn't working

Tags: php

It was recommended to me that I should use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` at the beginning of all my file names in case I move the page to another folder.

But, it's not working. Not sure why. I set up a test page, prayerpond.com/test5.php with a simple image and put the following...

```
<?PHP 
$doc_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/";
$root = substr($doc_root, 1);
?>

"<?PHP echo $root;?>main.css"

<img src="home/wiseman/public_html/ads/blank_ad2.jpg" />
<img src="<?PHP echo $root;?>ads/blank_ad2.jpg" />
<img src="ads/blank_ad2.jpg" />
```

I thought maybe the forward slash at the beginning was messing it up so I tried to subtract it but that didn't work either. In the example above, the first two images don't work but the third one does.

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: You don't want to use your document root. You want to use your *web root*.

Comment: Server variables like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and `$_SERVER['WEB_ROOT']` are not always guaranteed to be set automatically by your web server.  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php so do be careful about using them.

Answer (score 0):

[`DOCUMENT_ROOT` is the](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

> document root directory under which the current script is executing, as defined in the server's configuration file.

It points to the physical path of your file, which is in your case not wanted; you want to point to the publicly available URL. So you can either try use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead:

```
$root = dirname(__FILE__);
```

Or use another `$_SERVER` variable, e.g.:

```
$root = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately none of those worked. Not for images anyway. I know the hostname so I just added that manually. That didn't work for required() though. I had to use the document_root for that.